# Should (and can) we have a DNS-related question pointing to a canonical dupe on another SE site?

Tags: discussion

I had a question regarding the rationale behind DNS CNAME restrictions, which did *not* look on-topic for Server Fault site but *did* seem to meet the criteria for this SE and does not have an existing Q&A here afaict.

However, before I posted here I discovered that the question — despite seeming somewhat off-topic there since at least in my thinking it has more to do with networks than servers — has been asked multiple times to the point where it has ["a Canonical Question about CNAMEs at the apices (or roots) of zones"](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain/613830) there.

The content does not seem contentious at Server Fault, so I'm assuming they are content to keep the topic there rather than migrate.

But ignoring that and focusing from the perspective of this SE:

- *would* that Q&A be on-topic here as well?
- if so, *should* the question be re-asked here towards completeness?
- and if so, *could* the question **here** get marked as a duplicate of the "canonical question" **there** without itself getting migrated?

The goal being, that this site could include the question here but without having to rehash the answers already available there.

(And hopefully I'm not the only one who finds this amusingly meta to begin with ;-)

Comment: The answer to the source question would belong to SO as it relates to recursion. But I'm not sure there's any authoritative source (RFC) that states that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would that Q&A be on-topic here as well?

No, protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic for Network Engineering.

> if so, should the question be re-asked here towards completeness?

Not so, so the question is moot.

> if so, could the question here get marked as a duplicate of the
> "canonical question" there within the technical constraints of SE
> sites?

Not so, so the question is moot.

> The goal being, that this site could include the question here but
> without having to rehash the answers already available there.

No, SE does not allow cross-posting of questions, even if the question fits multiple sites; you must pick a site. Also, you cannot mark a question on one site as a duplicate of a question on another site.
It does not make sense to have a canonical question for a question that is explicitly off topic.

Comment: Ahh the OSI model strikes again. Simple enough, thanks! :-)